# How deep sleep and wake up works in an Android?

Tags: android, boot, android-wake-lock

I am using an Android tablet that works as a car radio. The default UI app is able to wake up from deep sleep (Device activation switch off for more than 10 minutes). But when I make an app and set it as a home app the app is not able to start as fast as the original manufacturer UI app in the device. So how the Android deep sleep and waking up is working in the device? How can I know more about it?

Comment: Built-in UI app has some special permissions which your 3rd party app can never have. Thats why it can wake up the device.

Comment: what it can't have those permissions ? have you also handled similar situation ?

Comment: I am not talking about the app waking up the device.. the device is woken up by hardware switch. but my custom helloworld app is not started as fast as the original UI boots up. that means my basic app is missing something...